# How to display workspace switcher in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: workspace-switcher

I'm using the Workspace Matrix extension (similar to Workspace Grid). Is there a command to display the workspace switcher?

Comment: control-alt {up arrow|down arrow}

Comment: That would switch the workspace and only briefly show the workspace switcher. I used to be able to bring up the workspace switcher then use it to switch workspaces. IIRC, the default hotkey for it was `Super-S`.

Comment: You could always click on `Activities` in the upper-left corner of your screen, or hit the `Super` key, and you'll see the workspaces on the right. There's also a GNOME extension (many of them actually) that lets you see/manage workspaces.

Comment: That shows the standard, non-grid workspace switcher, not the one for Workspace Matrix. Also, clicking on `Activities` is just the first step. I would like to be able to do exactly what `Super-S` used to do.

Comment: https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix/issues/35 indicates this functionality isn't yet available.